# Hybrid App : Running web app in WebView from files in native (local)

Tags: android, webview, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a hybrid app [Xpresso](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobigraph.xpresso). Because of performance issue we are planning to have our web app files (html, css, js & json) which were earlier hosted from server to be there in the local.

So earlier since the files are there in S3 bucket and are loaded in webview the server runs the app.

So if we have the files in the local what server will be there to run the app. One option which I can see is using Ionic but using an Ionic blank app itself has a size of 24 MB which I don't want.

So how can I run the web app in the webView. (gulp ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to this question is that nothing special needs to be done. Just the way how the web app is hosted in `S3` similarly a very similar structure needs to be followed and it will run automatically.

I do highly recommend everyone to go through this blog if you are making a hybrid app : https://medium.com/myntra-engineering/leveraging-native-power-in-webview-105d248fe71

Answer (score 1):

as you have correctly identified, there is little additional effort required to achieve this. You can simply refer the local files by their identifier just as though they were on the server. [This post from Cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42325660/hybrid-app-running-web-app-in-webview-from-files-in-native-local) explains how it can be achieved.

Hope this helped.